# adding JDatepicker in Jframe

Tags: jcalendar, jdatechooser

I want to develop a Swing desktop application with jlabel, JDateChooser and a submit button.

I am using below code :

```
public class Homeg {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        JFrame frame=new JFrame("date display");
        JDatePickerImpl datePicker;
        UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
        model.setDate(1990, 8, 24);
        model.setSelected(true);
        JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model,null);
        datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel, null);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JLabel label=new JLabel("Date");
        JButton submit=new JButton("SUBMIT");
        frame.add(label);
        frame.add(datePicker);
        frame.add(submit);
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And it is giving output having only JDatechooser.

Instead I wanted a output which must have a JLabel, JDatePicker and a submit button. Here it is showing only JDatePicker.

Answer (score 0):

You should always call pack() before making a call to setVisible();

```
{
    ...

    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Then to actuall make the date the submit button submit the date use:

```
JButton submit= new JButton("SUBMIT");
submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Date date = (Date) datePicker.getModel().getValue();
        /* do something with 'date' */
    }
});
```